# Set of points that makes a series converge absolutely is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of measurable functions. Prove that the set of points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ making the series $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converge absolutely is a **measurable** set.

I've already proven that the set of point making $(f_n(x))$ converge or be monotone is measurable. Maybe that can help to my new proof.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: The convergence of the series $\sum_n f_n(x)$ is equivalent to convergence of a certain sequence of $s_n(x)$ ($s_n$ measurable functions), by its very definition. The same applies for absolute convergence.

Comment: How can I use that?

Comment: You can then apply the result in the second paragraph (which you've already proven) with $s_n$ in place of $f_n$.

Comment: It's true. Thank you!!

Comment: If you write it as an answer I will valid it and the post will be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges absolutely iff $\left\{s_n(x)\right\}$ converges, where $s_n=\sum_{j=1}^n|f_n|$ is measurable for all $n$.

Using the result in the second paragraph, the set $\left\{s_n(x)\right\}$ converges is measurable, hence the result.

Similarly, the set on which $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges (not absolutely) is also measurable.